# SharePoint 2013 people picker retrieves user's old information

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, synchronization, sharepoint-2013

I have imported users from AD and keep syncing them for a while. Today two of users' display names have been changed on AD and SharePoint synced them correctly. Just to be sure, I checked users from User Profile Service App which looks OK. New names are appearing correctly.

Yet when I try to add a list item and select user from people picker, I get old user info. This also happens when I try to insert a list item programmatically.

Tried to delete users from SharePoint, however I still get same old users. Do you have any idea for solving this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. There was an another User Profile Service Application which was not used and not properly configured. Weird point is, that malconfigured app was not listed on service applications. I found it by using **Get-SPServiceApplication** cmdlet and removed it. After removal, did a full synchronization and voila! Now I can get current information.

Answer (score 1):

This is may be because entry in SharePoint's hidden user-list - **User Information List**.

Browse to this list - **http://{SiteCollectionURL}/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx**

Check for the display name of the users you have updated. If you see old user name instead of new/updated, delete these users from this list.

After this ask user to login to the same site again.

Comment: Refer this for more information on Hidden User Information (Userinfo) List -- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/marj/2016/03/14/what-is-hidden-user-information-userinfo-list-in-sharepoint-20102013-and-how-to-fix-when-it-causes-a-site-collection-to-show-old-user-metadata-properties-in-people-picker-control-or-in-a-person-or/